# Twilio Android Client - How to renew Capability Token for Device receiving Incoming Call

Tags: android, twilio, jwt

I have created a Twilio Client App for Android to communicate with other Twilio Android Clients.  On initialization of the app, a Capability Token is created (for the default time) to accept incoming calls and make outgoing calls.

The intention is that the device could receive a call at anytime.  For the device making the outgoing call, I create a new Capability Token when calling out.  However, the incoming device has no way of knowing (currently) that a call is incoming.  Does anyone know of a solution to this issue?

Thanks!

P.S. This is my first question on SO, so I apologize if it is lacking in anything.

Comment: Through experimentation, it seems that once the device has been initialized to receive incoming calls, even after the capability token expires, it can be renewed remotely.  This leads me to another question.

Is there a way to retrieve a list of clients (whether their capability tokens have expired or not) who have "initialized" on a specific Twilio account?

Comment: I just heard back from a Twilio Rep and they said that this 'remote renewal' of capability tokens for incoming calls will be discontinued with version 1.2.  For 1.2 it will be necessary for the incoming device to directly update it's capability token.  His suggestions were to refresh on a regular basis or trigger a refresh based on a timeout error (which I don't quite understand).  Another option I'v considered (hoping for a better solution) is to use GCM to notify the app of an incoming connection.

Comment: I have a same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing.
I reload the page with javascript.

```
Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
    $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
    location.reload();
});
```